# How to generally characterize $\operatorname{Ext}^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors

There's this [well known characterization of the first $\operatorname{Ext}$ group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1684166/167197) of two objects in a abelian category:

> There is an isomorphism between $\operatorname{Ext}^1(B,A)$ and the group of equivalence classes of short exact sequences of the form $A \hookrightarrow \_\_ \twoheadrightarrow B$. If $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, these are called the *group extensions* of $B$ by $A$.

Can we say anything crisp like this to characterize $\operatorname{Ext}^2$? Or $\operatorname{Ext}^n$ in general? [It looks like we can](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2535413/167197), but I am unfamiliar with $n$-extensions and the construction of the Baer sum of two chains.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have an answer in the link. What is it you don't understand?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff After staring at that section on Wikipedia for a bit, it does look a bit more straightforward than I thought. Initially the Baer sum looked scary, but that's fine, and just serves to put a group structure on $\operatorname{Ext}^n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is this description in terms of extensions of length $n$, but as far as I know it's not useful for anything; in any case I've never used it for anything. Here are three descriptions that are actually useful:

- $\text{Ext}^n(A, B)$ is the set of maps from $A$ to $B[n]$ (the chain complex which is $B$ concentrated in degree $n$) in the [derived category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derived_category). This is maybe the easiest way to see that for all $A, B, C$ there are natural maps $\text{Ext}^n(A, B) \otimes \text{Ext}^m(B, C) \to \text{Ext}^{n+m}(A, C)$ (it's just given by composition in the derived category); I think thinking about this map in terms of extensions is a pointless headache.
- $\text{Ext}^n(A, B)$ classifies extensions of $A$ by $B[n-1]$; one way to say this is that it classifies chain complexes $C$ fitting into a short exact sequence $0 \to B[n-1] \to C \to A \to 0$, up to a suitable equivalence relation.
- $\text{Ext}^n(A, B)$ is the $n^{th}$ homology of a chain complex $\text{RHom}(A, B)$ called the [derived hom](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A5W). In many situations it's not enough to consider the Ext groups and one must consider this entire chain complex, for example if $A = B$ derived endomorphisms have a [dg algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_graded_algebra) structure containing more information than just the corresponding graded algebra given by taking homology.

Comment: I would disgree with your comment in the first sentence. The exterior product in Ext is not hard to understand either in terms of resolutions, or of concatenation of extensions, or of total complexes of tensor products of extensions. All of these do have uses, for example in spectral sequences of change of rings. Your statements in the derived category have to be proved *somehow*, and I cannot see how there is any loss of difficulty here. I would say it is a nice way to see it, but I would be reluctant to say its the easiest way!

Comment: It would be interesting to note that in your last example, one can transfer the DG-algebra structure in the derived Hom to an $A_\infty$-structure on Ext, like in the case of the Yoneda algebra of a ring, which one can compute as the cohomology of $\text{End}(P)$ where $P$ resolves the trivial module. This is even more information than an algebra structure!

Answer (score 4):

You already found a description via equivalence classes of $n$-extensions in the link. This is described in more detail in some homological algebra books like those of Weibel and Hilton and Stammbach. In case the abelian category has some more properties, for example it is a module category, one can define the syzygy $\Omega^n(M)$ of a module $M$ as the $n^\text{th}$ kernel in a projective resolution of $M$. In this case one has $\operatorname{Ext}^n(B,A)=\operatorname{Ext}^1(\Omega^{n-1}(B),A)$ and one has a nice description of $\operatorname{Ext}^n$ via the description of $\operatorname{Ext}^1$ using short exact sequences. Another nice description is possible using derived categories and their $\operatorname{Hom}$, see for example the last chapter of the book by Weibel, or the book by Gelfand and Manin.

Comment: I'll also add that a clear explanation is given in MacLane's book Homology.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of keeping this post self-contained, I should include a description of how to characterize $\operatorname{Ext}^n$ as $n$-extensions as outlined in this [section on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_functor#Construction_of_Ext_in_abelian_categories).

---

For two objects $A$ and $B$ in an abelian category, define an *$n$-extension* of $B$ by $A$, as an exact sequence
$$
  0 
  \to A 
  \to X_1 
  \to \dotsb 
  \to X_n 
  \to B 
  \to 0
\,.
$$
Then we want to say two $n$-extensions are equivalent if there are maps $\{f_1, \dotsc,f_n\}$ such that every square in this diagram commutes:
$$
  \require{AMScd}
  \begin{CD}
     0 @>>> A @>>> X_1 @>>> \dotsb @>>> X_n @>>> B @>>> 0\\
     @.@V{\mathrm{id}}VV @V{f_1}VV @. @V{f_n}VV @V{\mathrm{id}}VV \\
     0 @>>> A @>>> Y_1 @>>> \dotsb @>>> Y_n @>>> B @>>> 0\\
  \end{CD}
$$

This relation is clearly reflexive and transitive. Showing that it is symmetric, and can indeed be regarded as an honest equivalence relation takes some work (look for a proof of the [short-five lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_five_lemma) to help). Under this relation, there is a set bijection between equivalence classes of $n$-extensions and $\operatorname{Ext}^n(B,A)$.

We can strengthen this result by imposing a group structure on this set of equivalence classes and saying that it and $\operatorname{Ext}^n(B,A)$ are isomorphic as groups. Let $X_n \times_B Y_n$ be the [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)) of $X_n$ and $Y_n$ over $B$, and let $X_1 +_A Y_1$ be the [pushout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushout_(category_theory)) of $X_1$ and $Y_1$ over $A$. Define the Baer sum of the two $n$-extensions above as
$$
  0 
  \to A 
  \to X_1 +_A Y_1 
  \to X_2 \oplus Y_2
  \to \dotsb 
  \to X_{n-1} \oplus Y_{n-1}
  \to X_n \times_B Y_n 
  \to B 
  \to 0
\,.
$$
This is another $n$-extension of $B$ by $A$. The Baer sum imposes a group structure on the set of equivalence classes of $n$-extensions, the identity element being the class of split $n$-extensions with a canonical representative

$$
X_i = 
\underbrace{A \oplus \dotsb \oplus A}_{\binom n i \text{ copies}} 
\oplus
\underbrace{B \oplus \dotsb \oplus B}_{\binom n {n-i+1} \text{ copies}}
\;,
$$

making it isomorphic to the group $\operatorname{Ext}^n(B,A)$.

Comment: Doesn't your definition (equivalent=connected w chain morphism) imply symmetry? It looks to me like the problem is transitivity because another n-extension can be connected to one of these with arrows pointing in the opposite direction. Or do you mean that it's possible to reverse given arrows somehow? Could you elaborate, please? Sorry for necroposting.